# PHP does not report parse errors if error is caused within declared namespace

Tags: php, namespaces, traits

fellow StackOverflowers!

I'm suffering from weird problem. Let me write a short description:

Here's my folder hierarchy

- \sys\core\core.php with declared namespace sys\core and class name core
- \sys\traits\singleton.php with declared namespace sys\traits and trait name singleton
- \pub\index.php (no declared namespace, includes autoload function which takes care of rest - loading files basing on namespace declaration)

**\sys\traits\singleton.php**

```
trait singleton {

    private static $_instance = false;

    public static function get_instance() {

        if( self::$_instance == false ) {

            self::$_instance = new self();
        }

        return self::$_instance;
    }

}
```

**\sys\core\core.php**

```
namespace sys\core;

class core {
    use \sys\traits\singleton;

    public function __construct() {
        $ =; // just an example, it shall produce a nice parse error but it wont :(
    }
}
```

And in the **\pub\index.php** I have

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);

// some constants defined

require('path/to/my/autoload/which/works/correctly.php');

use sys\core\core as core;

$core = core::get_instance();

$core->load_controller();
```

Basically, any kind of error (`parse error / warning etc`) is being shown unless is caused within a namespace. So, anything wrong in `\pub\index.php` gets reported correctly (as desired), but every error made in file with declared namespace, results with white page, with no errors displayed (despite error_reporting being set to `E_ALL` everywhere where it's possible - even in php.ini)

My config info:

PHP 5.5.0 (package from dotdeb.org) running via PHP-FPM
nginx 1.4.1 (package from dotdeb.org, also nginx's error.log is empty, even tho it saves any kind of PHP errors normally)
Running on Debian (Testing/Sid)

Any hints/tips what am I missing? I'll be thankful for any piece of info! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved (tho it was not connected to namespaces anyhow)

@ before include() is not silencing errors from include, it silences all errors thrown in included file (and I'm wondering since when it used to be like this...)

Anyway, question can be closed, utilized & forgotten